# vs2012 intellisense not working while adding multiple css classes

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I installed new vs2012 and i was working with HTML5 but some how when i tried to add multiple css classes.Intellisense show only one class which already is been added.

things i have already tried to fixed it:

1. I ve installed vs2012 update1
2. delete files from %AppData%Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas
3. reset vs2012 settings from Tools>export and import settings>reset all settings
4. I ve installed web essentials 2012

none of above worked for me can any one please help me out visual studio is getting annoying.

Comment: Are these classes declared 1) all in the same .css file 2) across multiple .css files 3) inline on the page (like <p style="font-weight:bold;>), or 4) directly on the HTML page (<style type="text/css">)?

Comment: I was also having same issue. Please install latest update. it should be fixed.

Comment: yeah all classes were in the same file